# Restricting SSH access to a specific list of commands

Tags: unix

I'm looking to build an application akin to [tilde.club](http://tilde.club) where a user has SSH privileges but a restricted list of available commands. I am a novice with Bash and Unix machines, so I consulted a friend who has a bit more experience. He vaguely addressed some security concerns without explicating, namely with jailed user environments being unsafe, virtual machines being unstable, and SSH tunneling.

Would anyone please shed some light as to...

1. What security issues I should be concerned about, and
2. How I may mitigate those issues to protect my server

If it matters, I only want the user to be able to use nano and a Python applet that I am writing. They should be restricted to their home directory and all subdirectories therein.

Comment: @Apero certainly! I would like to allow users to edit, create, and remove HTML files (and directories) in their home directory. I would also like for them to be able to run an interactive Python script that I will install on the machine. I can't name any examples sadly, but if you need any more information, feel free to ask. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

First, instead of setting the user's shell as `bash`, `ksh`,.. you could instead set it as [rosh](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Read-Only_SHell(rosh.c32))

Then, in `/etc/sudoers`, allow the same user / group of users, to only run some limited list of commands as another generic user who can run them, or as root, if required.

Also, I remember that some people define the "allowed commands" in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the target server, but then it would have to be read-only for the user, otherwise he could modify it.

References / Links for help:

http://cybermashup.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/
http://david-latham.blogspot.in/2013/12/restrict-commands-executed-via-pre.html
http://www.cmdln.org/2008/02/11/restricting-ssh-commands/